# How can I create a collection of the same type as a record in a table?

Tags: oracle, plsql

> **Background**
>
> I'm trying to create a procedure that moves data from a list of audit
>   tables to a different database periodically.
>
> To avoid generating massive undo, I want to do this 1000 records at a
>   time. For this reason, I will be bulk collecting the data into a
>   collection for each audit table with a limit of 1000 records at a
>   time, inserting the data into the remote table and then deleting the
>   fetched 1000 records in the forall.
>
> I will also be doing various other tasks (logging the data migration
>   for each table and sending notifications.
>
> Since, the number of audit tables is quite large, I don't want to
>   create a procedure for every table. So, I need to be able to
>   dynamically create a collection that is of the same structure as a
>   table.

---

> **Question**
>
> How can I create a collection of the same type as a record in a table inside a 
>   PL/SQL procedure?
>
> **Note**: the collection only needs to be of the same structure as the table **at that instant when the code runs**. I don't expect the collection to
>   dynamically change - I know that's not possible. Only at the instant that the procedure runs, it needs to be created with the same structure as the table, so that I can use it for the copy operations.

---

> **What I've already tried**
>
> I tried trying to create a dynamic SQL statement from the data
>   dictionary. I realized that I can do this for common types, and I'm
>   able to handle precision, varchar2 byte vs char, etc.. But I think it
>   might fail for some other data types/precisions combinations.

Comment: `How can I create a collection of the same type as a record?` by using `%rowtype` attribute. So it might be something like this `type t_col is table of your_table_name%rowtype;`

Comment: `But I think it might fail for some other data types/precisions combinations.` - such as?

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov what if we don't know the type in advance? I think that is what this is about.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov Ah, %rowtype is what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: @GurwinderSingh I was trying to dynamically create the collection by querying the data dictionary, since I did not know about the %rowtype attribute.

Comment: Oh great. I thought more I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Question**
>
> How can I create a collection of the same type as a record in a table
>   inside a PL/SQL procedure?

You probably need `%ROWTYPE` declaration, please take a look at very simple example:

```
CREATE TABLE abc111(
   x int,
   y varchar2(100)
);

CREATE TABLE abc222 AS SELECT * FROM abc111;

INSERT INTO abc111
SELECT level , rpad(level, 10 ,level)
FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10;



DECLARE 
   -- ====>  here %ROWTYPE declaration is used <========
   TYPE type_name IS TABLE OF  abc111%ROWTYPE;
   rec_var type_name;
BEGIN
  SELECT * BULK COLLECT INTO rec_var
  FROM abc111;
  FORALL indx IN 1 .. rec_var.COUNT
  INSERT INTO abc222 VALUES rec_var( indx ) ;
END;
/
```

---

```
SELECT * FROM abc222;

         X Y                                                                                                  
---------- --------------
         1 1111111111                                                                                          
         2 2222222222                                                                                          
         3 3333333333                                                                                          
         4 4444444444                                                                                          
         5 5555555555                                                                                          
         6 6666666666                                                                                          
         7 7777777777                                                                                          
         8 8888888888                                                                                          
         9 9999999999                                                                                          
        10 1010101010                                                                                          

 10 rows selected
```

Comment: The question states that there are large number of tables and to do this for each separately is quite time consuming. Isn't there a way to define rowtype at runtime i.e. table type is not beforehand?

Comment: That part is okay. I just needed the information in the "Question" section. To give a clearer idea about my intent, I provided the "Background" section, so that people might be able to suggest a better solution than what I was attempting.

Comment: @Gurwinder Singh - that's can be done easily using dynamic SQL - just run the code snipped from the answer in the loop using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE, and replacing table names in it dynamically.

Comment: @krokodilko Is it so? didnt really try. I'll just try it. Thanks