# How can I combine rowid into a collection of the same rowtype as a table?

Tags: oracle, plsql

> **Background**
>
> From Nicholas Krasnov and krokodilko's answer in the question
>   [How can I create a collection of the same type as a record in a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40958623/how-can-i-create-a-collection-of-the-same-type-as-a-record-in-a-table),
>   I found that you can use the %ROWTYPE attribute to create a collection
>   of the same type as a table.
>
> However, I need to also capture the ROWID of the table in the
>   collection, as I will be using it to delete those rows.

---

> **Question**
>
> How can I combine ROWID into a collection of the same rowtype as a
>   table?

---

> **What I've already tried**
>
> I created a nested type with the original type that is of the same
>   rowtype, with an additional field containing the rowid.
>   Code Sample below:

```
create or replace procedure p_test as
l_cur_limit pls_integer := 500;

type rec_with_rowid is record
(
    t1 mytable%rowtype,
    row_id rowid
);

type tab_to_be_moved is table of rec_with_rowid;

l_to_be_moved tab_to_be_moved;

cursor c_get_to_be_moved is
select mytable.*, mytable.rowid
from mytable;

begin  

open c_get_to_be_moved;
loop
    fetch c_get_to_be_moved
    bulk collect into l_to_be_moved limit l_cur_limit; --Fails here, as the collection
                                                       --is not of the same type
    exit when l_to_be_moved.count = 0;      

    for i in 1.. l_to_be_moved.count loop
        begin
            insert into mytable@remotedb values l_to_be_moved(i);
        exception
            when others then
                dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
                l_to_be_moved.delete(i);
        end;    
    end loop;
--        forall i in 1.. l_to_be_moved.count
-- Need rowid to delete, as the audit tables don't have PK for performance reasons
    commit;
end loop;          
close c_get_to_be_moved;

exception
    when others then
        dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);

end;

/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have at least two options.

1) Declare a cursor and the collection whose elements of `cursor_name%rowtype`;

```
create table foo( c1 number, c2 varchar2(11));


declare
  cursor c1 is
    select f.*
        , rowid as rid
      from foo f;
  type t_col is table of c1%rowtype;
  l_col t_col;
begin
  open c1;
  fetch c1 bulk collect into l_col;
  /*  further processing */  
end;
```

2) Create a view that includes `rowid` and then declare a collection whose element of `view_name%row_type`, or declare a cursor that selects from that view since you want to fetch and process certain number of rows at a time:

```
create or replace view v_foo as
  select f.*
      , rowid as rid
    from foo f;

declare
  type t_col is table of v_foo%rowtype;
  l_col t_col;
begin
 -- or declare a cursor
  select *
    bulk collect into l_col
    from v_foo;
  /*  further processing */  
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are defining the first type as a *table* while that should be for the second type. I would do the following (only one type definition is needed):

```
type tab_with_rowid is record
(
    t1       mytable%rowtype,
    row_id   rowid
);
```

**MY MISTAKE**

Once you have this type, you need to define one for a TABLE, something like:

```
type tab_with_rowid_T is table of tab_with_rowid ;
```

and then define a variable:

```
tab_with_rowid_V tab_with_rowid_T ;
```

Now, you can use this variable to receive the contents of the cursor.

Hope no more mistakes here.

Comment: +1 Fixed and I now updated the code sample in the question with your correction. However, the same error PLS-00597: expression 'L_TO_BE_MOVED' in the INTO list is of wrong type still remains.

Comment: This is not a valid Oracle's collection declaration syntax.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov I corrected the syntax in his sample to "record". But it still fails.

Comment: The approach of declaring a recordtype and then using it to create a type and variable is the only way I see it would work for ref cursor.